# hold one's breath

Tags: idioms

I was told that "holding her breath" is not used properly in sentence a. What about b and c? If the latter two sentences are okay, how do they differ from a?

> a. Leslie is holding her breath for the upcoming new smartphone scheduled for release next month.

> b. He held his breath while the results were read out.

> c. The whole world holds its breath for this speech.

Comment: (a) is not wrong, but we don't normally speak of 'holding one's breath' for an event that won't happen for a month - in fact we say 'Don't hold your breath' to warn someone that they may have a long wait. I would expect (c) to imply that the speech would be made quite soon; perhaps within hours, though obviously that's longer than a person could really hold their breath for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) is not wrong, but we don't normally speak of 'holding one's breath' for an event that won't happen for a month - in fact we say 'Don't hold your breath' to warn someone that they may have a long wait. See [Meaning of "but don’t hold your breath"?](/q/279973/104866)

I would expect (c) to imply that the speech would be made quite soon; perhaps within hours, though obviously that's longer than a person could really hold their breath for.